# SSH Key pairs with Ansible

Tags: ssh, ansible

I have setup an ansible environment with a control machine (centos) and 3 other remote hosts (centos). Everything is fine with regards to the actual functioning but I want it to work a little seamlessly I guess.
I have setup the ssh authentication using **#ssh-key-gen** on my master server and then used **#ssh-copy-id** to all my 3 hosts for the passphrase and it works.

Now each time I run my ansible command to these servers it asks me for passphrase and only then the command completes. I dont want that to happen. I tried defining that in my hosts file as you see below but that hasnt worked. I even tried with the **vars** and it doesnt work with that as well. When i run the command **#ansible servers -m ping** it asks me for the ssh passphrase and the it runs...

[servers]

10.0.0.1
ansible_ssh_user=root ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa

Thanks
A

Comment: This question is off-topic for StackOverflow. You can either generate keys without a passphrase or use an SSH agent. Besides, do some research on your own; here's one of the top results in Google: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12195/how-to-avoid-being-asked-passphrase-each-time-i-push-to-bitbucket

Answer (score 1):

> Now each time I run my ansible command to these servers it asks me for passphrase and only then the command completes. I dont want that to happen.

1. Generate your ssh key without passphrase.

or

2. Setup ssh key agent.

*This is a bit off-topic for SO*